# Menu de opções com botão direito do mouse em datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

Estou precisando criar um menu com algumas opções para que, quando for selecionado um registro em uma datagrid e clicar com o botão direito sobre esse registro apareça um menu com as opções para aquele registro.

Comment: Sim e qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Como criar esse menu @ramaral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para declarar um *context menu* para a sua *GridView* acrescente esse código à declaração dela:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Titulo do menu" Click="metodo_a_chamar">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="caminho_da_imagem" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Acrescente um `<MenuItem/>` por cada item que o menu deva conter.
Veja mais na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Show de bola, em ajudando como sempre.Obrigado @ramaral

Comment: como faço para o menu aparecer quando eu selecionar apenas uma linha? Pois minha opção será de acordo com a linha selecionada (nesse meu caso, só quero acrescentar a opção para excluir apenas).

Comment: Para responder teria que fazer alguns testes, imagino como isso possa ser feito mas não tenho uma resposta pronta. Sugiro que crie uma nova pergunta, assim outras pessoas poderão também responder.

Comment: Fiz outra pergunta, de qualquer forma, muito obrigado!

Comment: Quando eu tiver tempo e se ninguém responder, eu respondo.