# Popup ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, popup, devexpress

Estou tentando fazer um popup ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse dentro de um `GridView`.

Estou utilizando o evento `MouseDown` e o evento `MouseUp` para fazer o `popupControlContainer` aparecer e desaparecer.

mas como faria para ele aparecer aonde o mouse esta?

Em pesquisa, achei aqui no StackOverFlow essas duas perguntas, porém são para WPF e eu estou trabalhando com Winforms:

[Menu de opções com botão direito do mouse em datagrid](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65751/menu-de-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-bot%C3%A3o-direito-do-mouse-em-datagrid)

[Menu de opções com botão direito do mouse em linha selecionada em datagrid](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65970/menu-de-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-bot%C3%A3o-direito-do-mouse-em-linha-selecionada-em-datagrid?rq=1)

Tambem achei essa pergunta, porem é para componente .NET, preciso para DevExpress:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035144/right-click-to-select-a-row-in-a-datagridview-and-show-a-menu-to-delete-it

Código dos eventos `MouseDown` e `MouseUp`

```
 private void click_right(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) // click com o botao do mouse direto em cima do grid view
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) // botao direito
        {
            popupControlContainer1.Show();
        }
    }

    private void upclick_right(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) // botao direito
        {
            popupControlContainer1.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que é  **`popupControlContainer1`**?

Comment: @jbueno segue documentação: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsPopupControlContainertopic

Comment: @stderr obrigado vou ler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui implantar utilizando o evento `MouseDown` do `GridView`, junto com o componente `ContextMenuStrip`

[Documentação do ContextMenuStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // verifica se o item esta em edição ou se é um item novo
        if(editar == 1 || nCRM == 0)
        {
            // verifica se é com o botão equerdo
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                // exibe o ContesteMenuStrip na posição do mouse dentro do gridcontrol
                CRM.Show(gridControl1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
            }
        }
    }
```